# insert returning iterator

Tags: c++, insert, iterator, const-iterator

I am implementing `class graph`.
In similar to `stl` ,I think ,that the signature of insert function should be

`pair<iterator,bool> insert ( const value_type& x );`

For my class I have implemented `iterator` and `const_iterator`.
Should I define 2 i(overloaded) `insert` functions : one which will return `pair<iterator,bool>` and the second which will return `pair<const_iterator,bool>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no need. You can't call `insert` on a `const` collection anyway.